# Why adds OnCreateView the child fragments multiple times?

Tags: android, android-fragments

When onCreateView called second time it adds another instance of MyFragment. For example when this Fragment comes back from back stack, it shows two instances of MyFragment. Why? How should I prevent it?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.announcement, null);
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, new MyFragment());
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
 return view;
}
```

Comment: why are you doing a fragment transaction in onCreateView.

Comment: ok, where should I do it? in onCreate?

Comment: you don't need to. just inflate the view and return it, {if you need to prepare like add listeners, etc you can do it here}

Answer (score 2):

FragmentTransaction should done in onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, new MyFragment());
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

thanks to Atrix1987